# Authetication with tokens - proper way?

Tags: authentication, authorization

I'm designing RESTful API for many devices. But I have no idea how to handle tokens and store it in database(with expiration times).

My idea is following

Client sends GET request

```
GET /users/login 'username=Foo&password=Bar'
Response:  
{
     "logged": true,
     "token": "224md10c4u01420c1024u1209uMU24"
}
```

Server writes to tokens table

```
| ID |               token               | user_id |   expires   |
| 1  |   224md10c4u01420c1024u1209uMU24  |    4    |  21/01/2015 |
```

Then client receives token and when requesting for example:

```
GET /users/update "mail=foobar@example.com&password=topsecret"
Authorization: Awesome 224md10c4u01420c1024u1209uMU24
```

Server checks if token is active and exists(if not returns error).
If token exists and is active updates data

```
if token.id > 0 && token.expires > Date.now() {
     Users.getUserById(token.user_id).update(request.data)
     http.response(array('success'=>true))
}
```

And client gets

```
{
     "success": true
}
```

Is this way good and secure? I don't need OAuth2 because I don't plan to share API with third-party.

Thanks.
S.

Answer (score 0):

Hi first thing when you make and authentication process you don't want to send the log-in form with a GET request. It get be easy stolen, use post for sensitive date send over the net.

Second instead of token you can use sessionID so is no need to you another token.

In rest it seams to be OK. But there always my be hackers and stuff.

Hope this helped you.